# initializing class field with an object

Tags: php

I'm new to php so the question is dump. Take a look at the following code

```
class A {
    private $obj;

    public function A() {
        $this->obj = new Obj();
        //$this->obj->fff() works here;
        //still var_dump($this->obj) prints NULL here
    }

    public f() {
        //$this->obj is NULL here!!!
        //$this->obj->ff() throws an error
    }
}
```

**UPD** in `f()` I get `Fatal error: Call to a member function ff() on a non-object in ...`

how should I init `$obj` to see it in `f()`?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: It depends on what is inside f(). sometimes initialization with a simple new operator for object construction might fail when cloning is a must, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public function __construct() {
     $this->obj = new Obj();
}
```

I think the problem is you missed `function`. I am not really a `PHP` guy but I think `public function A()` will work too, but the `__construct` is preferred.

Edit: Now you added `function`. I am not really sure if my answer will help you then.

Comment: yes, I missed `function` while posting the question. Unfortunately `__construct()` does not help. Anyway thank you for answer!

Comment: Then maybe `new Obj()` doesn't work. What is inside its constructor?

Comment: Also is it `public f()` really or `public function f()`?

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in function name `A()` which s similar to class name. When you call `$a = new A;` actually `A()` method of `A` class is invoked. Use `__construct()` instead.

On my server this works fine:

```
<?php 

class A {

    private $obj;

    public function A() {

        $this->obj = new stdClass();

    }

    public function f() {

        var_dump($this->obj);

    }

}

$aa = new A;

$aa->f(); // Prints `object(stdClass)#2 (0) { }`

?>
```

Looks like you have a problem with with your `Obj` class. And why don't you place `function` in `public f() {` in your class definition?

Comment: Changing `A()` with construct does not seem to help. Updated the question

Comment: So what is your problem now? Check if `$this->obj` is really an object you expect by `var_dump($this->obj);` right after it's initialisation. And give us your full code. How do you create instance of `A` class, how do you invoke its methods and so on.